# Do you need to add Google Play services if using react-native-push-notification?

Tags: react-native, google-play-services, react-native-push-notification

I’m using ‘react-native-push-notification’ and keep seeing references to Google Play services in stackoverflow answers. Do I have to use Google play services since I’m using push notifications?

Comment: If you are using firebase to send remote push notifications then you must.

Comment: @KishanBharda I'm not using Firebase at all. Would I still need it?